# Kendo foreign key column filter not working for the category name

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

http://jsbin.com/cadevaha/1/edit?html,js,output 
click the above link where i have reproduced my situation. I have a foreign key column for category which returns the category name based upon the Product name value. i want to filter based upon the foreign key value as well as category name.In simple terms, filtering is not happening for the category column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not specified the type of the column.

This is done through the dataSource.schema.model.fields configuration.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Kendo Dojo Grid</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [{
                field: "productName"
            }, {
                field: "category",
                values: [{
                    text: "Beverages",
                    value: 1
                }, {
                    text: "Food",
                    value: 2
                }]
            }],
            dataSource: {
                data: [{
                    productName: "Tea",
                    category: 1
                }, {
                    productName: "Ham",
                    category: 2
                }

                ],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                      fields: {
                            category: {
                                type: "number"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            filterable: true
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cadevaha/5/edit?html,js,output 
in the above link i tried as u explained but still the filtering is not working for the Role coloumn. can u take a look into this one and help me out. @Petur Subev